# What is the purpose of using pass statement in python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I know the `pass` is a reserved keyword which does nothing when interpreted by the python interpreter. I am just curious to know what is the real purpose of it.

Let's say

```
for i in [1,2,3]:
   pass
   print(i)
```

When it is interpreted it gives nothing, then what is the purpose of existence of this reserved keyword. I researched a little but not able to find the exact purpose of the `pass` keyword, Just curious to know.

Comment: That for loop isn't valid, so I would expect it to throw an error.

Comment: To make it possible to use indentation to denote blocks (and not something like { } ) and still make it possible to have empty blocks. There must be some duplicate of this...

Comment: `pass` is the empty statement, it does *nothing*. You use it when you *must* have a statement syntactically. Like defining an empty function: `def foo(): pass`. You can't leave a function definition empty, you must have at least one statement, so you use `pass`.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: already handled.

Comment: @RanjithUdayakumar Your original code was not valid; it was subsequently fixed.

Comment: @chepner, I just missed " : " so that I added it, I was mentioned "it is valid" because erip mentioned "Pass is not valid in Loop".

Comment: He never mentioned `pass`; he just said the loop wasn't valid, which it wasn't without the `:`.

Comment: @chepner oh okay, I misunderstood...